# Storage Spaces Recovery

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage-spaces

Windows Server 2012 R2. 25 low cost disks and one SSD. OS is installed on the SSD, and the low cost disks are configured as a storage pool (with a couple of hot spares).

The SSD has failed. Through testing I have determined that attaching a new SSD and re-installing the OS makes the storage pool available again (automatically), but NOT the volume (and consequently the data contained therein).

Question: Is it at all possible to attach/mount/bring online that volume, and gain access to the data? Or is a full restore from backup required?

Comment: In effect your moving the storage pool and storage spaces to a new server so the guide for that should apply: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/12/24/windows-server-2012-how-to-import-a-storage-pool-on-another-server.aspx

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I was looking for and has worked perfectly. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are in effect moving the storage pool and its storage spaces to a new server a TechNet article titled "[Windows Server 2012: How to Import a Storage Pool on Another Server](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/12/24/windows-server-2012-how-to-import-a-storage-pool-on-another-server.aspx)" should apply. A summary of the steps:

1. Make the disks available to the server,
2. Make the storage pool read-write.
3. Attach the virtual disk.
4. Online the resulting logical disk(s).